# Storing set of std::arrays of any (but constant) length

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr, stdarray

Is there a way to store a set of std::arrays of any (but constant) length where the length of the array can later be used in a constexpr?

I guess standard containers are out of question, but there might be a template solution somehow. All of the information is available at compile time, isn't it?

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

// Class storing an array of any (but constant) size
struct A {
    const std::vector<std::string> container; 
    const int container_size;
    A(const std::vector<std::string>& v, int size) : container(v), container_size(size) { }
};

int main() {
    // List of variable length const arrays and their sizes
    std::vector<A> myAList {
        A({ std::string("String1"), std::string("String2") }, 2),
        A({ std::string("String1") }, 1)
    };

    // How would I go about using the size of each array in a constexpr?
    for (auto const& a : myAList) {
    // Example constexpr:
    //  somefunc(std::make_index_sequence<a.container_size>{});

    // 2nd example converting to actual std::array
    //  std::array<std::string, a.container_size> arr;
    //  std::copy_n(std::make_move_iterator(a.begin()), a.container_size, arr.begin());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

More details were requested, so here goes. I don't really care how the array is defined, anything that works... The exact constexpr used is the one in the example code, `std::make_index_sequence<CONSTEXPR>{}`. *I just know that I have a set of constant arrays that are defined at compile time, and it should somehow be possible to refer to their length elsewhere in a constexpr*.

Heck, I'd actually be fine with just storing the lengths:

```
// Class storing an array size
struct A {
    A(int size) : container_size(size) { }
    const int container_size;
};

int main() {
    // List of lengths
    std::vector<A> mySizeList { 2, 1 };

    for (auto const& a : mySizeList) {
    //  somefunc(std::make_index_sequence<a.container_size>{});
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The simpke answer is you cannot.  The more complex answer boils down to 'maybe, depending on exactly constexpr operations, and how exactly you construct said arrays, and other details you did not include', and the implementation is tricky.  Are you only going to call one specific `somefunc` in exactly that way?

Comment: @Yakk `somefunc` is a variadic template function that applies arguments to a function called via a function pointer. I need a compile time index sequence to unpack the arguments, thus `make_index_sequence` is required.

Comment: Is that a yes, or a no?  **"Are you only going to call one specific `somefunc` in exactly that way?"**  I hereby assume "yes", and I have added an answer below.  It also passes in a `const&` to the `vector` in case you need that too.

Comment: Yes, I expected an answer to that.  That is usually why I ask questions: to get answers.  ;)

Comment: Sorry if the code in the question was too vague. I tried to avoid making it all about my specific situation in an attempt to make it useful to others, but sometimes it's hard to find the right balance.

Comment: **−1** The question asks about `std::array` and constant sizes but neither is present in the example code. I don't see what this question is about. Please do provide some example that involves the things asked about.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Added more explicit use of std::array to make question clearer. I wasn't originally instantiating std::array objects in the example code since they can't be stored in a vector - so I stored vectors with sizes instead to illustrate the point. The question is summarized twice: *"Is there a way to store a set of std::arrays of any (but constant) length where the length of the array can later be used in a constexpr?"* and *"...I have a set of constant arrays that are defined at compile time, and it should somehow be possible to refer to their length elsewhere in a constexpr."*

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yeah, since the arrays need to be stored and passed around, a run time loop seemed like the obvious choice. But if we can evaluate the constexpr at the point of construction and store the result for later use, the problem is avoided (as Yakk's answer shows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that you want to call `somefunc` with both the `const&` to the `std::vector` and the `index_sequence`, and that you only want to call `somefunc`.  It also offers support for a `somefunc` with an extended signature (simply pass a 3rd argument with the return value and/or the additional arguments, which will be passed after the `std::vector<T> const&`).

Failure to align the size of the vector with the size passed in will result in badness if the size passed in is longer than the vector.

It also assumes you know what function you are calling at the point of construction.  This can be generalized to any finite set of functions you want to call at the point of construction, naturally.

The technique used is called "type erasure" or "run-time concepts".  I erase down to the concept of invoking your `some_func` with the index sequence in question during construction, and store that erased operation in `f`.

```
template<size_t N>
using size=std::integral_constant<size_t, N>;

template<
  class T, template<class...>class Operation,
  class Sig=std::result_of_t<Operation<size<0>>(std::vector<T> const&)>()
>
struct eraser;

template<class T, template<class...>class Operation, class R, class...Args>
struct eraser<T,Operation, R(Args...)> {
  std::vector<T> data;
  R(*f)(eraser const*, Args&&...);
  R operator()(Args...args)const{
    return f(this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  template<size_t N>
  eraser( std::initializer_list<T> il, size<N> ):
    eraser( il.begin(), size<N>{} )
  {}
  template<class...Ts>
  eraser( T t0, Ts... ts ):
    eraser(
      {std::forward<T>(t0), std::forward<Ts>(ts)...},
      size<sizeof...(ts)+1>{}
    )
  {}
  template<size_t N>
  eraser( T const* ptr, size<N> ):
    data(ptr, ptr+N),
    f([](eraser const*self, Args&&...args)->R{
      return Operation<size<N>>{}(self->data, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    })
  {}
};
template<class T, size_t ... Is>
void some_func( std::vector<T> const&, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  std::cout << "called! [#" << sizeof...(Is) << "]\n";
}
template<class N>
struct call_some_func {
  template<class T>
  void operator()(std::vector<T> const& v) const {
    some_func( v, std::make_index_sequence<N{}>{} );
  }
};


int main() {
  using A = eraser<std::string, call_some_func>;
  // List of variable length const arrays and their sizes
  std::vector<A> myAList {
    A({ std::string("String1"), std::string("String2") }, size<2>{}),
    A({ std::string("String1") }, size<1>{})
  };

  std::cout << "Objects constructed.  Loop about to start:\n";

  // How would I go about using the size of each array in a constexpr?
  for (auto const& a : myAList) {
    a();
  }
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52de5ea6fcdfc904)

Comment: That's some pretty badass template code there! After lots of tweaking and trying to understand your code I ended up using some of the concepts, and it now works beautifully!

Comment: I don't suppose you know of a way to prettify the `size<N>{}` integral_constant definitions (aside from macros)?

Comment: `template<size_t N> constexpr size<N> sz() { return {}; }` gives you a function `sz` where you can `sz<0>()` if you consider that prettier?  You could also pass the `std::string`s to a variardic ctor of `eraser` that counts the args for you.  So you'd get `std::vector<A> myAList{ { "String1", "String2" }, { "String1" } }` which seems prettier.  Untested version added to post above.

Comment: Smooth, I got arg counting to work, so now the whole thing is transparent to the user. C++14 is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is something like [`dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray) which is moribund.

You certainly can't use its size in a constant-expression though, because it's not a compile-time constant (that's what the "dyn" in the name refers to).

To use the `container_size` in a constant expression the type `A` must be a literal type, so it must have a `constexpr` constructor, which is going to be very difficult to do if you want to pass it a `vector`!

You could do something like this, but it's pretty disgusting:

```
#include <array>

struct A
{
    void* ap;
    std::size_t n;
    template<std::size_t N>
      constexpr A(std::array<int, N>& a) : ap(&a), n(N) { }
    template<std::size_t N>
        std::array<int, N>& get() const { return *static_cast<std::array<int, N>*>(ap); }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return n; }
};

int main()
{
    static std::array<int, 3> a{ 1, 2, 3 };
    constexpr A aa(a);
    constexpr int len = aa.size(); // OK, this is a constant expression
    std::array<int, aa.size()>& r = aa.get<aa.size()>();        
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question even after look at the two current answers. I don't think I'm stupid about this.